# Are there extended editions of Harry Potter movies #3-#8?

Tags: harry-potter, alternate-version

I know that there are extended cuts of Harry Potter films #1 and #2 (*Philosopher's Stone* and *Chamber of Secrets*), for example part of Harry Potter Wizards Collection BluRay set.

But that set doesn't have extended cuts for any other 6 films.

Do those 6 films starting with *Prisoner of Azkaban* have extended cuts? If no, is there any explanation of why not?

Comment: There are some [deleted scenes](http://whatculture.com/film/15-awesome-harry-potter-deleted-scenes.php/2), but nothing of any significance in terms of plotline, mostly just extra background for characters.

Comment: I have watched every movie today on free form and they all have extended scenes in them. I have the movies without extended scenes too. So I have seen both so Im not sure why they are saying they dont exist.

Comment: I saw those movies on Freeform too. They did have scenes not on my DVDs. If I had recorded them I could point out scenes that were added. Someone was watching with me and noticed added parts as well.

Comment: I'm from Argentina, now living in USA. The 31st of July I watched the movies on Freeform and I spot many scenea I've never seen before. And since then I searched the web for the same question, I guess that there are extended versions of the movies.

Comment: @Flor - can you provide any details on the scenes? And were you watching original movie or a fan cut with deleted scenes re-added? (I know Star Wars has those, not sure about HP)

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no extended or director's cut version available for those movies. No official word was given as to why.

Speculation suggests they don't want to say there will not be any, as they can always release them in the future for extra money. Of course, given the number of years since these movies have been released, and the main series ended, it's not likely they will.

Comment: Is there any evidence for lack of extended cuts? E.g. some full listing of all releases etc...? Thanks

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative. But IMDB has a section called Alternative Versions for each film,  typically tv gore/sex/time and deleted scenes.

Answer (score 4):

The extended versions of the first 6 movies are on the Ultimate editions Blu Ray only or the single movie extended versions on dvd offered only by Target years ago. The extended versions include the deleted scenes as part of the movie. The theatrical version have the deleted scenes as part of the extras.

Comment: Can you provide some links to more info?